# I need information on using the google console php api

Tags: php, google-speech-to-text-api

I've been using a lot of speechtotext provided by Google.

I specify that I use the PHP API.

I have only one problem:

I need to have, as a result of the transcription, not only the simple text but also the CSV file containing the following fields:
start time, end time and, of course, the relative text.

This CSV file is currently downloaded by hand from the Google console.

I, on the other hand, have to get that data from the PHP script where, at the moment, I only get the text.

I need this for transcription of relatively long audio, in which there are pauses of several seconds.

Does anyone know how he does it? Always with the PHP API.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: no, this is my first time asking this question. made yesterday.